# set route for sitemap on angular2 universal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How can we set the route so that sitemap can be access through URL :

< domain_name >/sitemap.xml

My app routing module is kind of like this :-

```
export function getHomeModule() {
  return System.import('./+home/home.module' + (process.env.AOT ? '.ngfactory' : ''))
    .then(mod => mod[(process.env.AOT ? 'HomeModuleNgFactory' : 'HomeModule')]);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ], {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
  ],
})
```

I am using angular universal starter kit [Angular Universal Starter Kit](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the **server.ts** file in the **src** folder :-

```
app.route('/sitemap.xml')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname,'/sitemap.xml')));
  });
```

**Update:**
As for **Angular universal 2.1**(around)
*server.ts* has following for importing path

```
import * as path from 'path';
```

so resolution was somewhat,

```
const ROOT = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));
```

For the current **angular universal version 2.6**

*server.ts* has following for importing path

```
import {join} from 'path';
```

so resolution is shifted to,

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Tor Helgevord's article about angular server side rendering and dynamic sitemap here : http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score -1):

Update to Angular 6 (universal) :

```
app.route('/sitemap.xml')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER,'sitemap.xml'));
  });
```

Comment: That's not an update..... :/ rather than importing whole path... you are importing just join.