# Generating sitemap for angular app using it's routes

Tags: angular, typescript, url-routing, sitemap

I'm trying to generate sitemap for each module using express server.

Below is my project structure.

```
-Root
--ModuleA
--ModuleB
--ModuleC
```

I've generated root level sitemap.xml and it has reference to ModuleA sitemap.xml. Like below

```
<sitemap>
    <loc>https://wwws.example.com/moduleA/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
    <loc>https://wwws.example.com/moduleB/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
```

Now the problem is, I need to generate sitemap.xml based on it's routes for each individual modules(A,B,C).

I can use `app.get(`moduleA/sitemap.xml`)` but how will pass the routes ?

Please help me with the design so that I build it peacefully.

Comment: Check if relevant - https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/how-to-create-dynamic-sitemap-xml-using-javascript-ee4d9ba7402a

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44062362/9427395 is useful?

Comment: but this is not for angular.